# My name sounds like a bird - Riddle

Tags: riddle

> My name sounds like a bird 
> Whole body is like tongue of a lizard 
> Am different colors 
> And I well can be very littered
>
> My energy melts away over time 
> But not quite like an ice 
> And when not taken care of 
> I'll collect dust and lice

First one to answer correctly *will* be marked as best answer.

**UPDATE:
If you write an answer but want to change it or make a second guess, please update your answer, keeping the new guess above the old guess. Please do not overwrite.**

Hint: It's not a food. And it is quite sticky.

Comment: Should line 4 be "And I very well can be littered" or "And I can be very well littered", or is this odd phrasing deliberate?

Comment: Welcome aboard! Wonderful start.. :)

Comment: Beautiful puzzle! The answer clearly will be some kind of candy or sweet whose "name sounds like a bird".

Comment: @Martin Wrong. It's not a food.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it:

> Duct tape

Sounds like a bird:

> "Duck" tape

Body like the tongue of a lizard:

> Sticky, like has already been mentioned

Am different colors:

> Duct tape is sold in a variety of colors

Well can be very littered:

> Not sure if there's more to this one, but scraps of duct tape can be left around as litter

Energy melts away:

> As with other answers, it loses its stickiness over time. Also, old duct tape can start to melt over time if stuck to something out in the heat, etc

It'll collect dust and lice:

> Even when on the roll, the sides of a roll of duct tape can be sticky enough to collect dust

Comment: Correct, correct, correct! I'm sorry I didn't see your answer earlier! This is exactly correct! Good job Ben. Accepted as best answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are:

> Wax or a candle

My name sounds like a bird

> Apparently there's a bird called a waxwing

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> Wax is sticky when melted

Am different colors

> Candles

And I well can be very littered

> Grammatically incorrect play on lighting candle?

My energy melts away over time / But not quite like an ice

> Candles melt as you burn them (using their energy)

And when not taken care of 
I'll collect dust and lice

> People tend to have decorative candles that end up just being dust collectors

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Velcro

My name sounds like a bird

> Like a crow

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> Velcro rolls up like a lizard tongue. Lizard tongues might also have little barbs on it

Am different colors

> Velcro comes in all colors

And I well can be very littered

> lint and stuff gets stuck in between the barbs

My energy melts away over time 
But not quite like an ice

> After using it, the edges start curling up and it doesn't hold as firmly

And when not taken care of 
I'll collect dust and lice

> another reference to stuff that gets stuck in Velcro

Answer (score 3):

This is a second guess.

Is it a(n)

> Sucker

My name sounds like a bird

> The Yellow-bellied or Red-breasted SapSUCKER

Whole body like the tongue of a Lizard

> They get all sticky

Am different colors

> Just about every brand of sucker comes in many colors, including suckers that have different colors

And can well very be littered

> Discarded suckers can litter a floor, just look in any Elementary school hallway on November 1st.

My energy melts away over time
But not quite like an ice

> A suckers energy (and I don't know if this means caloric content or just the fact that the sucker exists) melts away, not quite like ice with repeated licking/sucking

And when not taken care of,
I'll collect dust and lice

> The aforementioned stickiness can make all sorts of pick cling to a sucker.

---

Is it a(n)

> arrow

My name sounds like a bird

> sparrow

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> long, narrow and forked at the end

Am different colors

> the fletchings can be very colorful

And I well can be very littered

> definition of Litter from Merriam-Webster:
>  a messy pile or group of things

My energy melts away over time 
But not quite like an ice

> arrows wear out over time. After a few years of use, they become less straight, and cannot fly as far.

And when not taken care of 
I'll collect dust and lice

> If left unattended, the arrows will collect dust, and lice if the fletchings are made from true feathers

Comment: Sorry for the late reply...Not what I was going for, but I like the idea. +1!

Comment: It might be better to put your latest answer at the top so that it's what people see first. If you want to separate the two guesses, you can use <hr> to draw a horizontal line between them.

Comment: +1, *a litter* is the pouch on your back that you draw them from.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> Sandpaper

My name sounds like a bird

> Sandpiper

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> Rough

Am different colors

And I well can be very littered

My energy melts away over time

> Loses grit

But not quite like an ice
And when not taken care of
I'll collect dust and lice

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure I know the answer, but I haven't managed to fit the first line yet. It's

> CHEWING GUM.

*My name sounds like a bird*

> This is the line I'm still struggling with.

*Whole body is like tongue of a lizard*

> Many lizards have sticky tongues with which to catch insects, and chewing gum is also sticky.

*Am different colors*

> Chewing gum comes in many colours.

*And I well can be very littered*

> It's often thrown away, littering the streets.

*My energy melts away over time

 But not quite like an ice*

> Chewing gum loses its chewiness after some time, but it doesn't literally "melt" in the same way ice does.

*And when not taken care of

 I'll collect dust and lice*

> If you take out a piece of chewing gum and leave it somewhere, it will gather dust and all sorts of muck.

Comment: Why 3 downvotes?!!

Comment: I don't see any problem with your answer~

Comment: Really close, really close !!! It's not a food though!

Comment: $(+1)$ Are people forgetting this is @Randal'Thor we're talking about? Everyone knows his answers are great! I mostly upvote them before I even read them, because I know what I will read: brilliance! :D

Answer (score 2):

You may be a

> Post-it

In fact:
My name sounds like a bird

> [Stilt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stilt)

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> It's sticky and useful!

Am different colors 
And I well can be very littered

> They can be all colors, scattered everywhere.

My energy melts away over time 
But not quite like an ice

> It's not melting like ice, but its sticky power decreases over time.

And when not taken care of 
I'll collect dust and lice

> I think we all know what happens to a post-it when it's not pinned to a surface...

Answer (score 1):

> A mohawk

My name sounds like a bird

> Hawk.

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> You need something sticky to hold it up.

Am different colors

> I've seen them in many colors

And I well can be very littered

> Littered with... I don't know.

My energy melts away over time
But not quite like an ice

> I don't imagine it'll stay up forever, but it won't liquify.

And when not taken care of 
I'll collect dust and lice

> Hair attracts lice. Stickiness attracts dust.

Comment: $(+1)$ Nice try ;)

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for making everyone wait so long. The correct answer, in fact, is

> Duct tape.

I'm pretty sure the rest is pretty self-explanatory, but still, these are the descriptions:

My name sounds like a bird

> Duct tape sounds like duck tape. (There's even a company that sells duct tape called Duck Tape.)

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> Duct tape has a sticky side (lizard tongues are sticky)

Am different colors

> Duct tape is avaliable in different colors.

And I well can be very littered

> People litter pieces of duct tape all the time.

My energy melts over time

> Duct tape loses its stickiness over time

But not quite like an ice

> This line is the clue that the word 'melt' is used as a metaphor in the previous line

And when not taken care of
I'll collect dust and lice

> If the sticky side is left, eventually it collects dust particles and hair

Thank you to all who participated in my riddle!

Comment: @Len Didn't see it. Changed best answer. Thanks len.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Lollypops?

My name sounds like a bird

> I can't get this one

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> It rolls like a lizard's tongue

Am different colors

> Colorful candy!

And I well can be very littered

> Once you're done eating...littering is no good

My energy melts away over time
But not quite like an ice

> Sugar melts

And when not taken care of
I'll collect dust and lice

> Leave it alone and it'll get dirty

Comment: @programmersdude I assume this is not the answer you're looking for?

Comment: It _is_ sticky. Try again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Do you by chance know the policy of SE on giving answers or answering your own question. Thanks!

Comment: @programmersdude Puzzling.SE is a bit of a special case on this issue: on other SEs where people ask for help, it's fine if they can answer their own question. Here you've presented this riddle as a *challenge*, so it'd be frowned upon to answer it yourself unless attention has completely died out and nobody else is interested (or if someone has answered correctly but you want to give a 'canonical' answer explaining all your intended interpretations). I suggest giving it a few more days; I'm still working on it and others may be too.

Comment: @programmersdude The question is still near the top of the active questions list (that's how I found it) so there's still a good chance that someone will come by soon with the right answer

Comment: @programmersdude I think it's time for some hints, ran out of ideas already here~

Answer (score 0):

I think you're

> pork

My name sounds like a bird

> stork

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> uncooked pork is pink like a tongue

Am different colors

> depending on how you cook it, the color will change

And I well can be very littered

> with salt and pepper

My energy melts away over time

But not quite like an ice

> a heated steak will eventually get cold

And when not taken care of
I'll collect dust and lice

> improperly handled pork can collect germs and parasites, and is one of the worst things that you can eat (unfortunately i know from experience)

Comment: I don't think this is it ... why like the tongue of a lizard rather than anything else with a pink tongue? [Lizards don't neccessarily have pink tongues anyway.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue-tongued_skink#/media/File:Blotched-Blue-Toungue-Alpine-phase.jpg)

Comment: @randal'thor i assumed just for the rhyming

Comment: Sorry, I like your way of thinking, but...that's not really the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of copy pasta, but the answer is:

> A star

My name sounds like a bird

> Starlings are small to medium-sized passerine birds in the family Sturnidae

Whole body is like tongue of a lizard

> A lizard uses its tongue for maintenance (eating, drinking, cleaning, etc.). A star's body maintains its nuclear reactions.

Am different colors

> Red, yellow, white, blue, etc.

And I well can be very littered

> Universe-wide, in fact.

My energy melts away over time 
But not quite like an ice

> Stars spend about 90% of their existence fusing hydrogen into helium in high-temperature and high-pressure reactions near the core. Such stars are said to be on the main sequence. The duration that a star spends on the main sequence depends primarily on the amount of fuel it has to fuse and the rate at which it fuses that fuel.

And when not taken care of 
I'll collect dust and lice

> In larger stars, fusion continues until the iron core has grown so large that it can no longer support its own mass. This core will suddenly collapse, and the shockwave formed by this sudden collapse causes the rest of the star to explode in a supernova, resulting in a neutron star or black hole, both of which will consume any dust or lice in its vicinity.

Comment: Nope sorry that's not really it. However I like your very clever way of thinking...